# Looking for resources for designing tables to analyze user behavior on my company's ecommerce app/website

Tags: database, analytics, product, etl, data-science

My startup has a lot of event data for users using the app or website. I'm an analyst that wants to build etls to turn this raw data into useful tables to do analytics on. Does anyone have any suggests or resources I could look at to understand what the industry standard is for this? Looking for a framework to help guide which tables to build.

Currently we are organizing the data at the session level. We have a session properties table which describes useful properties for every session thats happened on our platforms. This is then used to build a basic funnel to see where users are dropping off before conversion. Unfortunately our product is such that there are multiple paths to conversion so one funnel doesn't capture all of it.

Comment: So Google Analytics?  Or something similar?

Comment: Not looking for a tool like Google Analytics. I want to know how to organize all of our raw event data. What tables should I build to make it easier to analyze our product data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is, essentially, "How do I start building a data warehouse from scratch." By your asking the question at all, I think it's likely you'd need several more years of dedicated experience before you could sit down and knock that out all by it yourself.

It is therefore my professional opinion that you should instead think about the problem in a different way.

Your question implies future tasks of Analyzing User Behavior, when in point of fact analysts create value by Testing Hypotheses Against Business Outcomes. Generally, this will involve testing things that you hope will:

- Improve Marketing ROI

  - By channel (PPC, SEO, Affiliates, etc.)
- Improve Conversion to Email Signup

  - Email Marketing Effectiveness
- Improve Conversion to Sale
- Improve Customer Retention / LTV
- Etc. etc.

That's a pretty short list. Pick the one with the highest likely return on analysis investment, and start there.

Now it's time to build out good A/B testing facilities. A/B testing generates revenue. Funnel analysis was the most common form of paralysis by analysis in the mid-1990's; it's nearly eradicated so don't let it spread now. Those A/B testing facilities should record detailed performance data. Start setting up tests and execute them. Maybe you've already got somebody working on this... that's awesome.

As you find yourself planning to test a new Acquisition/Conversion initiative:
- You should then build out supporting internal datasets that contain your KPIs and data that align with levers that marketing can pull... e.g., Facebook lookalike lists can contain what data? I can target ads based on what criteria? Our customers have what attributes? Which prospects converted to sale? Then you have the data you need to tell Marketing how to make more money.

As you find yourself planning to test a Revenue Improvement initiative:
- You should then build out internal datasets that contain your specific KPIs and any behavioral data necessary to support or reject the hypothesis being tested. This might include multiple customer-engagement tables (site visits, emails sent/opened/clicked, sales). Lots of the tests you'll do will look a whole lot alike, so these analysis tables will iteratively grow and improve.

Over time you'll find that you've unintentionally built a data warehouse from scratch, and that it does a pretty good job of functionally serving the business. Once your startup gets big enough, they'll hire somebody to completely normalize everything, and it'll then take two years for their data warehouse to eventually align with your numbers -- and only then will it subsume your homegrown warehouse.

Since we're already giving away the farm here: you're nearly always going to eventually need your own spin on following basic table concepts. This is off the top of my head, but notice how all the tables intuitively join to each other:

- Campaigns (ids, organization, urls, dates)
- Sessions (CampaignID, EmailID, UserID, entry URL, date, conversion indicators)
- Pages (PageID, SessionID, UserID, date, URL, previousPageID, nextPageID, eventID)
- Tests  (TestID, description, link to assets on file, begin/end dates, hypothesis)
- TestSessions (TestSessionID, campaignID, SessionID, TestID)
- Users (UserID, email address, date, CampaignID, SessionID)
- Sales (UserID, SessionID, date, ItemID, amount)
- Items (ItemID, Date, description, unit price)
- Email (EmailID, UserID, send date, opened date, clicked date)

Good luck!